# Central limit theorem and convolving a function with itself infinite times

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution, central-limit-theorem

There is something I don't understand about the central limit theorem in the frequancy domain.

The central limit theorem tells us that if we have $n$ probability density functions $f_i$ then
$$h=f_1*\cdots*f_n$$ approches a gaussian distrabution, but let's say $f=f_1=f_2=\cdots=f_n$ that means the convolution of all of them in the frequancy domain is
$$F\{h\}=F\{f\}^n$$ so if the ratio between the frequancy with the largest amplitude to the second largest amplitude in $f$ is $r$ then in $h$ it is $r^n$ which is infinite. So that means $h$ has only one frequancy so it's a sinusodial not a gaussian. What am I missing?

Comment: In order to ensure the limiting function is still a probability density function, it's necessary to rescale the convolution. This is quite natural, since convolution tends to "diffuse" the mass distribution and you have to counteract this effect in order to describe the asymptotic behavior of the iterated convolution.

Comment: @SangchulLee what do you mean by rescaling? Do you mean multiplying by some constant? Because if you do then it doesn't affect what I said because it doesn't affect the ratio between the largest and and second largest frequancy since both of them are multiplied by the same rescaling factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall $h$ is the density of $X_1+\dots X_n$ (where $X_i \overset{\text{i.i.d}}{\sim} f$, but the CLT deals with $(X_1+\dots X_n)/n$, provided of course that $X_i$ are centered and have variance 1. The FT of the density of this is
$$\left( F \{ f \} \left ( \frac{k}{n} \right)\right)^n$$
And so if the ratio between 'the largest amplitude' and 'the second largest amplitude' in $F\{f\} $ is $\lambda$, say, then this ratio becomes $(\lambda/n)^n$ which tends to 0 as $n$ tends to infinity.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\frac{(F\{f\}(k))^n}{n}$?

Comment: Isn't the FT of the pdf of $X_1+X_2$ is $(F\{X_1\}*F\{X_2\})(k)$ or is it $(F\{X_1\}*F\{X_2\})(k/2)$?

Comment: @TomerWolberg The pdf of $X_1 + X_2$ is $(f * f)(x)$. The FT of the pdf of $X_1+X_2$ is $(F\{ f\}(k))^2$. The FT of the pdf of $(X_1+X_2)/2$ is $(F\{ f\}(k/2))^2$.

Comment: @TomerWolberg The rescaling is in the space domain not the frequency domain. A rescaling in the space domain corresponds to a rescaling of the argument in the frequency domain.

Comment: oh right, I understand